# GKE istio deployment setting returns a 503 error when accessing it

Tags: devops, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-gateway

I'm trying to set at my GKE a deployment which works with HTTPS load balancer on istio.
I installed istio when the istio-ingresss is defined as NodePort and created an Ingress on gke with following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: istio-ingress
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    # If the class annotation is not specified it defaults to "gce".
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "ingress-frontend-config"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: istio-ingressgateway
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: istio-ingressgateway
    # Enable use of manually pre-defined global static IP
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: test-ip-address # A gcp ip address constantly set
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true" 
    # Enable use of a GCP-managed certificate through a ManagedCertificate resource
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: global-test-dev-cert # A gcp manged certificate for the host
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          # In this case we don't go directly to app-specific services,
          # but first to the Istio ingress-gateway
          # We use port 80 because it is the "ingress-like" port of the ingress-gateway
          serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
          servicePort: 80
```

After deploying the basic httpbin of istio I try to acces it with the following gateway and virtual service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: httpbin-gateway
  namespace: svc
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "httpbin.test.com" # DNS set to the Ingress IP
        # - "*"
    - hosts:
        - "httpbin.test.com" # DNS set to the Ingress IP
        # - "*"
      port:
        name: https
        number: 443
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: PASSTHROUGH
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpbin-vs
  namespace: svc
spec:
  hosts:
  - "httpbin.test.com" # DNS set to the Ingress IP
  gateways:
  - httpbin-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: httpbin   
        port:
          number: 8000
```

And when I access it through the browser I get a 502 Error. In the istio-ingressgateway logs I get a 404 error route not found.
But when I switch the hosts to

```
hosts:
        - "*"
```

The wildcards gives me access to the httpbin app.

I also tried changings the virtual service to

```
tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - httpbin.test.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: httpbin   
        port:
          number: 8000
```

The same problem occurs.

Comment: how did you test the connection? from your local device to GKE?
what address are you pointing in order to test?

Comment: From my local device to gke. The host is defined to an gke ingress static ip addresa

Comment: if you are using public IP address, you need to specify host header(in your case httpbin.test.com) in your request, I suggest you use your own domain and change the gateway settings to your own domain

Comment: The domain being used is my domain. The httpbin.test.com is just an example. But the domain being used is mine. And is set in the gateway. And the error still occurs.

Comment: please try to set the host for gateway : your public DNS. and for virtual service, set the host to httpbin.<the namespace>.svc.cluster.local

let me know if it cloud help

further reading
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/

Comment: I have tried it, and still the same problem.